# Windows 2003 IIS problems

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6, iis

I ran a IISCnfg.vbs script to import a iis config from another machine. Now I have the following issues:

1. When I open IIS Manager it lists IIS as version 5.0 (this is a win 2003 system)
2. I get an error message in EventViewer when I try to start IIS service. The error message is "The system cannot find the path specified".

Also there are no Websites listed under the server name. Although I think this is because the service can't be started.

I tried to restore from a backup using IIS Manager and I get the following error "The parameter is incorrect".

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you try to import from a Win2000 machine to Win2003?  What is the exact command you ran to do the export and import?

Comment: No this is a clean Win2003 build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try uninstalling IIS from Add/Remove Programs in Control Panel, rebooting and then installing it again.

Comment: wouldn't that destroy his backup of the metabase though?  IIS reinstall doesn't require a reboot AFAIK.

Comment: It probably doesn't, but I'd anyway do it, just in case...

Comment: Reinstalling fixed the issue. I restored my sites from a backup.